# c++ dynamic memory Allocation in stack

Tags: c++, memory-management

When we allocate a memory dynamically of 5 elements in heap then why it is displaying more than 5 elements???
In this program I have made char pointer str and given dynamic memory allocation, but when it accepts the size of dynamic memory it is displaying more elements than given size .For eg:-If I have given 5 character array ,it is displaying more than 5 characters of the string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int tos;
    int l;
    char *str;
};

class balancing
{
    struct node s;

public:
    balancing();
    balancing(int len);
    void balance();
};

balancing::balancing()
{
    s.tos=-1;
    s.l=0;
    s.str=NULL;
}

balancing::balancing(int le)
{
    s.l=le;
    s.str=new char[s.l];
    s.tos=-1;
}

void balancing::balance()
{
    int length;
    char ch1;
    cout<<"Enter the String"<<endl;
    cin>>s.str;
    cout<<s.str;
}

int main()
{    
    int len;
    cout<<"Enter the Length"<<endl;
    cin>>len;
    balancing b(len);
    b.balance();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What string do you enter for `cout<<"Enter the String"<<endl;
    cin>>s.str;`?

Comment: Just use `std::string` or at least `std::vector<char>` please.

Comment: cin has no idea about the size of you char array. It will write to the memory until your input finishes. This a string overflow and the result may be very tricky since it depends on the current status of your system.

Comment: When using `cout << ...`, don't forget to null-terminate the contents of the allocated `char[]`, otherwise it will exceed the bounds of the array into surrounding memory until it finds a nul byte, or crashes with a memory access error. Otherwise, use `cout.write()` instead, and pass in your `char[]` length explicitly.  In fact, you should also use `cin.get(...)` instead of `cin >> ...` to ensure you don't exceed the bounds of the array when reading data into the array

Comment: When you enter more than the length of the string you are writing into memory which is not allocated for the variable, so you may be overwriting part of your OS, for example.

Comment: @shell32 ..ya I got it but, still one question is, here you explained, cin accepting input string as it is having no idea about length of actual allocated string (which is 5) now instead of showing 10 bytes of memory, it should provide segmentation fault (as it is displaying such a memory which I had not created)

Comment: @gauriindani The overflow is only a potential reason for segmentation fault. Seg fault means you are accessing a virtual memory address that is not mapped to your process memory space or you don't have corresponding privilege to do the specific operation against the memory address. And the memory is allocated by page, not byte. When you overflow the array, it may write to the remained space of the page or overwrite the data follows the array. In such case, no segmentation fault since you are accessing valid memory. If you provide a large input, such as 100KB or 1MB, you might see a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to,

```
char str[2]={'H','i'};
cout<<str; // why doesn't this print 2 characters?
```

The answer is because in order to use a character array as a string, it must be null terminated. Any string processing code that expects a null character will carry on until it finds one (or causes a problem because it didn't).

Comment: Suggested tweak to clear up a bit of ambiguity: "because *character arrays representing* strings *must* be null-terminated."

Comment: cin will add a null terminator after the string automatically.